# link 2 tables in one columns in mysql node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax

I've 2 tables(orders & productOrder) and I want to make them link in column call orderId which exist in both of them to be shown in '/' route..the problem that i got an array from AJAX which include the data of orderproduct table from '/orderproduct' route in the page '/order/new' route which I select the data of order table in but can't post them in the same time..

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    var orderProduct = new Array();
    $("#review-products input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
                  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                  var message0 = row.find('#check').val();
                  var message1 = row.find('.name').text().trim();
                  var message2 =  row.find('.currency').text().trim();
                  var message3 =  row.find(".foo").val();
                  const result =  {check: message0,name: message1,p: message2,q:  message3 ,total: message2 * message3}
                  var hh = orderProduct.push(result);
            });
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {selectedProduct: orderProduct , sumTotal: totalPrice},
            url: '/order/product',
            success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
            }
          })
           })
```